# Sleep time of server causing Node.js to run for long

Tags: node.js, sleep, polling

I have put a random sleep time of 1-5 sec on the server which I am polling but the node takes indefinitely huge amount of time to process. With no sleep time it just works fine.

```
async.eachSeries(opt, function(entry, callback) {
            request({uri:entry, method: "GET"}, function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                    console.log('Yes ' + entry);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('No '+entry);
                }
                callback();
            });
        }, function(err) {

        });
```

"opt" is the array of sites being polled.

Comment: How large is `opt`? `eachSeries` processed each site after the previous one, so if each request takes between 1 and 5 seconds and your array is large, it *will* take a lot of time. With [`eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) you can run an X number of requests concurrently.

Comment: @robertklep - What if there is only a single "url" in the array which is being polled say 5000 times. Is it possible to achieve concurrency?

Comment: Yes. Unless the server forbids it or your machine blows because you bring up too many connections at once.

Comment: @harry4 I think that `request` has a limit on how many concurrent connections it allows for a single host. That limit is based on [`http.agent.maxSockets`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets), and is 5 by default (which means that if 5 connections are active to the same host, `request` will wait until one of those is done before it will create a new connection to that host). You may want to read the `request` docs on how to change that (provided you want to).